# New TYPO3 ver. 10.4 install shows 404 on all sub-pages

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-404, sites, typo3-10.x

I have a brand new TYPO3 10.4 install with a bootstrap sitepackage.

My page tree is this

```
Home
-> Building Management
--> Building Rules
```

Home shows fine, but all of the lower pages throw a 404 using the speaking url's, even from autogenerated links in the menus.  I can still navigate using index.php?id=2, but this is not enabled at all by default.

If I set the language link to /en/ (rather than /) then no pages work, not even the home page.

I built the same site on my development server with the same version of typo3 and the same site package and it works as expected, just not on the production.  Any idea where to look for a solution? Here's a pic of the site page[sites-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fLcP.png)

Comment: If I understood well you have problems with your local instantion? First, check if you have `mod_rewrite` enabled within your Apache config - preferable with `php_info()`, also make sure that your Apache uses `.htaccess` file for URL rewriting.

Comment: Thanks. The .htaccess was a clue.  What appears to have happened is that the .htaccess file was not updated during the typo3 install.  We copied one from another working install of 10.4.4 and that fixed it.

I think there is a step in the install process that checks if there is a .htaccess file, and if there is then it doesn't copy or insert the required changes.

Once we copied this accross everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.htaccess` was a clue. What appears to have happened is that the .htaccess file was not updated during the TYPO3 install. We copied one from another working install of `10.4.4` and that fixed it. I think there is a step in the install process that checks if there is a `.htaccess` file, and if there is then it doesn't copy or insert the required changes. Once we copied this across everything worked fine.